# Android, Eclipse, and SVN, how can I make them all happy?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I am creating an Android Application with a team of others. Typically I use netbeans, and I have never had trouble with netbeans or svn. But as eclipse has the android plugins, we are using eclipse.

What I need to do is check in my current a android application, so that then my team members can all check it out(as an android project) and continue to develop and test on their own computers.

Current when we check out a project from SVN, eclipse does not recognized the project as an android project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3166947/62576 or especially http://stackoverflow.com/q/4296481/62576 didn't answer this for you?

Comment: You do know that there's a netbeans plugin for android development too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had this problem too. The thing is that the ".project" file was not imported in SVN; because of this Eclipse will add a new ".project" file whenever and however you check out the project from SVN; the other part of the problem is the poorly designed "Android Project from Existing Code" option.

Solution:
- delete the .project file from your working copy
- ["optional"] move the project folder somewhere else (because the "Android Project from Existing Code" option will not work if you try to create the project in the same place)
- create new project and select "Android Project from Existing Code"

After creating the project commit the newly generated .project file to SVN; this way the others will be able to simply click "Check Out" and start working :)

Note: Make sure to also commit the other android related files (e.g. project.properties)